# How to select rows based on specific column values - shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I am new to shell script and I'm not sure why this code isn't running. I have tried over 50 variations of this line at this point using if or int($2), but I keep getting errors. Is there another way to do this?

```
awk -F , '$1 == "Yes" && $2 == "Yes" { print }' data1.csv > data2.csv
head data2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts(tried code), keep it up. Kindly do add samples of input and expected output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: What version awk are you using (check that by `awk --version`)?

Comment: What is your OS? And what is the error you get?

Comment: When I run `awk --version` I get the output `['awk: not an option: --version']`. I'm assuming that’s why my code isn't running. Is there a way to fix this? @Daweo